# Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV) when getting data as input in the vector of struct

Tags: c++

Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV). [Link to code](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/qEELDyhr4c) 
The code gives Segmentation fault error due to the input taken to store the values for vector of struct.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct s{
    int a;
    int d;
};

int main(){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        vector<s> v;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
             cin>>v[i].a;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
             cin>>v[i].d;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input is:**

```
6
900  940 950  1100 1500 1800
910 1200 1120 1130 1900 2000
```

Comment: You have an empty vector, with nothing inside. What do you expect to see as first element of that vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're accessing the vector outside of its bounds. The vector is empty, but `v[i]` tries to access elements of the vector that don't exist. Therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined.

I suspect that you may have intended to use the vector's constructor that takes a count of elements as an argument.

Comment: how to store the input element in the vector in this case?

Comment: @MohitMalik If specify the number of elements for the constructor of the vector, then the vector stores that many elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works. I specify the size of the vector when I construct it.

```
    vector<s> v(n);
```

Compile code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct s{
    int a;
    int d;
};

int main(){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        vector<s> v(n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
             cin>>v[i].a;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
             cin>>v[i].d;
        }
    return 0;
}
```